# How did Kilgrave know it was Malcolm Ducasse?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, jessica-jones-2015

In Jessica Jones, Malcolm Ducasse

> comes under Kilgrave's influence, which is particularly horrifying because he was Jessica Jones' very first savee after she decides to use her powers for good.

Within the universe of the show (i.e., I get that this is a plot device, but I'm less interested in what went on in the writer's room),

> how did Kilgrave know to use Malcolm Ducasse against Jessica? It didn't seem like Kilgrave could see Malcolm's face in episode 5.

Or was this just an unbelievably unfortunate coincidence?

Comment: First thought is, It wouldn't take much for him to find someone with the skills to track him down and compel them.  Don't know if this is gone into in the show at all though.

Comment: This is speculation, but it'd be easy to find Jessica's home (since she advertises herself as a P.I.) and put the 'fluence on her neighbours.  All he'd have to do is say "Tell me about your relationship with Jessica" and he'd know everything he needs to know.